# Value vs. Object

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, c++17

[C++17]

When a prvalue expression is evaluated, the [standard](http://eel.is/c++draft/basic.lval#5) says that it result in a value. In the case of `5` the expression is a prvalue, and it evaluates to the value `5`.

However, when you have a prvalue, mainly an initializer for an object, such as `Foo{}`. What would the value of this expression be? Would the result be the temporary object created by the prvalue-to-xvalue conversion? This brings on my broader question of **the difference between a value and an object**.

Comment: An object has an address. A value is not required to have an address.

Comment: I would guess an object is a region of memory/storage that has a value, where a value is a well defined bit configuration. But I don't know/remember what the standard says.

Comment: How can you get the value of an object of class type without calling the constructor, and by association creating the object?

Comment: So maybe *object = where* and *value = what*...?

Comment: @krys `struct foo{int x;}; foo{7};` -- I created a value of class type and no constructor was called.  It may also cause temporaty materialization of an object.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont ok, so what would be the result of a prvalue being evaluated?

Comment: @krys What domyou mean by "evaluated"?  I don't see that word mentioned in that part of the standard.  If you remove the word "evaluated" then the prvalue `foo{7}` has the value of a struct `foo` whose `x` has value `7`?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Sorry I worded that poorly. What would the result of a prvalue be? The standard [basic.lval.5] states: `The result of a prvalue is the value that the expression stores into its context. `, but I'm not entirely sure what that means. What is the value of a prvalue? What does it mean to store into an expressions context?

Comment: This question needs a version attached, because the rules for temporaries are significantly different

Comment: The value of `Foo{}` would be the total state of the object `Foo` after default initialisation.

Comment: @Peter So evaluating a prvalue would require an glvalue to be created, as you can't get the state of default initialized `Foo` until you actually construct it?

Comment: @KrystianS - that's the way I would interpret it, yes.

Comment: @Peter What is the "total state of an object"?

Comment: @curiousguy - total state of an object is the combined set of values of its members.   For example, if a `struct` or `class` has two members of type `int`,  the value of that `struct`/`class` is the combination of the value of those two `int`s it contains.

Comment: @Peter OK for math numbers but what if they contain pointers? What if the object initialization registers it on some global structure?

Comment: @Peter A constructed object isn't a pure state; it has an distinct identity. In some case the address is never used for any other purpose then making lvalues that are assigned to. You could call that a pure constructor or pure type if all member functions act that way.

Answer (score 4):

> **[[intro.object]/1](http://eel.is/c++draft/intro.object#1):**
>
> An object is created by a definition, by a new-expression, when implicitly changing the active member of a union, or when a temporary object is created. **An object occupies a region of storage in its period of construction, throughout its lifetime, and in its period of destruction**.

Regardless of whether a prvalue has class type like `Foo{}` or not, as the literal `5`, is considered a value and that value is then used to initialize an object if it's really necessary, this is when the value is materialized into an object.

> **[[class.temporary]/2:](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.temporary#2)**
>
> The materialization of a temporary object is generally delayed as long as possible in order to avoid creating
>   unnecessary temporary objects.

<sub>Under that same section you'll find a list describing when temporaries are materialized.</sub>

Comment: So that would make `Foo{}` a value, even if it has not been constructed yet?

Comment: @KrystianS Its a constructed value having class type `Foo`.

Comment: So what would the value of `Foo{}` be exactly?

Comment: @KrystianS the same way you said, the expression `5` is a prvalue having the value `5`, you can say the expression `Foo{}` is a prvalue having the value `Foo{}`, these values can then be used to initialize an object. in that respect the statement *"the value `5`"* is not that different from *"the value `Foo{}`"*

Comment: Obviously, the way the the actual value is stored in the object is different than `Foo{}`, so that part confused me. I was trying to figure out how an objects value could be represented as a ASCII string haha.

Comment: [intro.object]/1 is probably the most inept part of the std. If you believe that part is taken seriously by serious ppl, you are seriously misinformed.

Answer (score 3):

The *value* is an abstract concept. A value is associated with a set of realizations that characterize or identifies the value. For example with a value of 10$ one could buy a book or a meal.

A value can have multiple representations. For example the 10$ can be represented by coins or stored as bits in a bank account.

An *object* is to a *value* what a *bank account* is to a *quantity of money*: the object (/the bank account) holds the representation of the value (/10$). This is described in [[basic.types]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.types#4):

> The *value representation* of an *object* of type T is the set of bits that participate in representing a value of type T.
>   Bits in the object representation that are not part of the value representation are padding bits.

Then in [[intro.object]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/intro.object#1) it is specified that an object is associated to a region of storage:

> An object occupies a *region of storage* in its period of construction ([class.cdtor]), throughout its lifetime, and in its period of destruction ([class.cdtor]).

This distinction between the object and its value is more sensible if **we consider an abstract machine** with a central processor unit, that performs operations, and a separated memory where can be stored objects (that holds value representation). When an operation is performed on a value, the value is loaded into different cpu registers. So the value in the cpu does not have the same representation: a contiguous sequence of bits as it had inside the object. Moreover any cpu is free to represent the value in a register as best suit its need.

When the cpu executes an operation, it does it on a piece of value stored in a register. After that operation is performed, the cpu can save the result in memory, inside an object, or continue to operate on the value.

The decomposition of an operation in operations on values and in storages or loads from or to objects, appears in the standard:

- a **load** is an **lvalue-to-rvalue** conversion [[conv.lvalue]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv.lval#1) *A glvalue of a non-function, non-array type T can be converted to a prvalue.*
- all **operations** in c++ will result in a sequence of fundamental **operations with built-in** meaning. Most of **these operations applies on value** (prvalue) and not on an object. Before these operations are performed *lvalue-to-rvalue* is applied [[expr]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr#9) *Whenever a glvalue expression appears as an operand of an operator that expects a prvalue for that operand, the lvalue-to-rvalue,[...]*
- the results of these built-in operations, that operate on value, are always prvalue (a prvalue is just a value not associated to any object). Then the resulting value can be used as operand of an other built-in operation, or **initialize an object** (a **store** operation in the memory of our machine), [[basic.lval]](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/basic.lval):*A prvalue is an expression whose evaluation initializes an object or a bit-field, or computes the value of the operand of an operator, as specified by the context in which it appears.* So in our machine representation, the act of storing the value in an object is a store.

To illustrate this, let's analyze this simple piece of code:

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]){
  int j = 2*argc+1;
  }
```

1. `2*argc` built-in operator * is called with two arguments `2` and `argc`. `argc` is an lvalue, so *lvalue-to-rvalue* is applied. The value of `argc` is **loaded** in a cpu register (2 could be an [immediate](https://en.wikichip.org/wiki/immediate_value)) and the `multiply` **operation** is performed.
2. the result of `2*argc` is a prvalue, that is directly used as the first operand `(2*argc)+(argc)`. Then the resulting prvalue of this last operation is used to initialize the object `j`: the resulting value is **stored** in the memory representation of `j`.

Comment: So in the case of an lvalue-to-rvalue  conversion, the actual value of the object is obtained instead of the object itself?

Comment: @KrystianS Yes. And this only when takes place lvalue-to-rvalue conversion that the value of an object is [accessed](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/defns.access) (in the sense of loaded): *The C++ standard does not specify explicitly that it is lvalue to rvalue conversion that is responsible for causing an access. There is reason to believe that it is, because otherwise certain simple expressions become undefined.* source [gcc documentation](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-8.2.0/gcc/C_002b_002b-Volatiles.html#C_002b_002b-Volatiles)

Comment: The standard specifies that in the case of lvalue-to-prvalue conversions, if the expression has class type, a temporary will be copy initalized. Wouldn't that also result in an object, and not a value?

Comment: @KrystianS Indeed. Object of class type are never passed as parameter of built-in operators. Only built-in operators takes value as argument. User defined operators overloads and all functions declare either an object parameter or a reference. lvalue-to-rvalue conversion is never applied to argument of these functions (or operators).

Answer (score 1):

A value is a concept; an object is a thing with a lifetime.  This distinction tends to be much more important for class types with complex constructors, but the rules apply equally to all types.

Consider this simple program:

```
std::string foo() { return std::string{"Hello"}; }

int main() {
    std::string f = foo();
}
```

`foo` does not create an object.  Creating an object would involve calling the class's constructor to begin the object's lifetime.  For `std::string` that would likely involve allocating memory and copying characters, and for fairly obvious reasons we would like to avoid doing that too many times.

Instead, `foo` returns a value.  It returns the concept of 'a string initialized with the characters "Hello"'.  Eventually, `main` is able to take that abstract concept and construct an object to represent that value.  Because of this distinction, only one object is ever created, so the extra cost of beginning and ending object lifetimes only needs be paid once.

Comment: So could you theoretically say that the value is `std::string{"Hello"}`?

Comment: Kind of.  The expression `std::string{"Hello"}` represents the value 'a `std::string` initialized with the string "Hello"'.  That value will eventually be materialized into an object, but it could pass through several steps before that happens.

Comment: Ok. This doesn't really pertain to the question, but the value of a glvalue, such as `f` in the above example would simply be the object `f`, correct?

Comment: Yeah.  Outside of prvalues, there's not much distinction between an object and the value it represents.

Comment: Ok, so in all cases, a prvalue never represents an object, as something such as `Foo{}` would be converted to a xvalue. Prvalues only represent values/initializers.

Comment: Right, think of prvalues as blueprints for creating an object.  It's only when they get converted to an xvalue or glvalue that an actual object gets created.

Comment: So whenever a prvalue is evaluated, a glvalue is created.

Comment: Yes, I believe that's accurate.  Kind of like quantum mechanics, as soon as you try to observe the prvalue's state, it will get materialized.

Comment: [basic.lval]/1.2 `A prvalue is an expression whose evaluation initializes an object or a bit-field, or computes the value of an operand of an operator, as specified by the context in which it appears.` Yup, its true for the most part!